How to fixed the continent name on 3D earth in Reactjs, TypeScript and Threejs
I am using Threejs in my Nextjs 14 application I am implementing 3D earth glob using Gltf which is coming. However, I am not able to show the text of the continent name on their continent. I wanted to show fixed text on the continent for example text name is Asia so this text is fixed in Asia content whether the animation around is should be always present there and the same for another continent's name. Please help me solve this problem
Earth.jsx
"use client"

import React, { useRef } from "react";
import {  useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";



export default function Earth(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/globe/earth.gltf");
  const earthRef = useRef();

  useFrame(() => {
    if (earthRef.current) {
      earthRef.current.rotation.y -= 0.002;
    }
  });

  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <mesh
        ref={earthRef}
        geometry={nodes.Object_4.geometry}
        material={materials["Scene_-_Root"]}
        scale={3}
      >
        
      </mesh>

    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/globe/earth.gltf");

Earth3D.tsx
"use client";

import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Environment, OrbitControls, Text } from "@react-three/drei";
import Earth from "@/components/landing/Earth";
import * as THREE from "three";

const Earth3D = () => {
 
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas shadows className="mt-8">
      <ambientLight />
        <directionalLight />
        <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
        <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Earth />
        </Suspense>
        <Environment preset="sunset" />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  );
};

export default Earth3D;


There are many options, depending on how you want the text to interact. The simplest one, in my opinion, would be to add floating vectors in the GLTF model (in Blender before exporting). Make sure to name the vectors, and on component load, attach a sprite containing the names of the continents (so they'll always face the camera) as children of each respective vector.
If you don't want to modify the GLTF file, you can make an array of vectors, and attach them as children of the earth model on component load, and use them as anchor for the name sprite.
